# Using powershell to move fullscreen app/game to secondary monitor

Tags: powershell

Can anyone tell me, if it's possible to capture a running process/app that's running fullscreen, and move it to a secondary monitor?

I realize there are applications like UltraMon that can do this, but I'm wondering if maybe it would be possible using powershell?

Answer (score 3):

I don't know if it is possible, but you might want to give [WASP](http://wasp.codeplex.com/) a look.

Comment: well... I only tested it with one program, but it didn't quite pan out the way I wanted to - I was able to force it into windowed mode, and from there move it around and expand the window to be "nearly full screen". I guess with DirectX in the mix, it's gonna be quite difficult though :/